# Reference encrypted password in XLDeploy curl request

Tags: curl, xl-deploy

I want to use XLDeploy to - as part of a deployment - perform a curl request. For this I intend to use advcmd.Command

The request required authorization though. So I would like to place the username for this request in the environment-dictionary under entries and the password under encrypted entries. This is customary in our project and used alot for things like database or ldap passwords.

The curl command looks something like this:

```
type: advcmd.Command
command: curl --location --request POST 'http//url.with.placeholders' --user {{`{{user}}`}}:{{`{{password}}`}}
```

This approach, however, does not seem to work: upon deployment I get the following error:

**The deployable value resolved to an encrypted value, but this field is not a password.**

I guess I´m trying to do something that is not intended? How can I work around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating your variable twice which won't work (+ some syntax error)
You should do this instead :

```
curl --location --request POST 'http//url.with.placeholders' --user "{{user}}:{{password}}"
```